# What would be simplest way to search for a YouTube video and find the link to the first result?

Tags: c#, api, youtube

I'm looking for a simple way to add a youtube video to my little application I made for myself.

Basically I want to find the URL for the first result of a given query.

What would be the simplest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Not that it is not possible but it would be against the TOS, and can have legal consequences. You could only stream very low quality 3gp streams through rtsp using the Youtube api. Anything else requires using their embedded player.

Comment: @Marino: How is finding a link illegal? I only want to find the url and forward the users to it via their browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [YouTube API](http://www.youtube.com/dev). I'm sure it will allow you to accomplish this.

Comment: you should add to this that the search api will give info required to use the Youtube Custom Player: http://code.google.com/intl/hr/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#custom_player - not using their player is against the TOS - probably because it allows you to remove commertial propaganda :/

Comment: Thanks for the addition, Marino - I haven't used the API so I don't know the "rules" myself.

Comment: as we are talking www.youtube.com gives Http/1.1 Service Unavailable :DD